# How can I save changes on a dynamic tree on c?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, tree, malloc

I'm building a database for a project, every entry has an RB-Tree that contains its attributes, but with the function that I made I cannot save the changes of the trees. I create and link the new nodes but when I return the new nodes are lost

x is the attribute (relation) identifier, used to look inside the tree and see if the relation already exists or not. id_orig is the entry of the database which I have to ad the relation to. tree * radice is the root of the tree and tree * nil is the nil pointer (substitute to NULL).

Add_rel_list is the function used to add a new relation after adding it on a new tree node if there isn't one.
insert fixup is used to check that the RB-Tree is balanced and respects it's definition

this is the add attribute function

```
    struct tree *insert(unsigned long int x, char id_orig[50], char nome_relazione[50], struct tree *radice, struct tree * nil){ /*devo creare un nuovo nodo dell'albero */
    if(radice==nil){
        //this part is used to create a new root of the tree
    }
    else{
        struct tree *newleaf=malloc(sizeof(struct tree)); /*creating a new node*/
        //struct rel_list *lista=malloc(sizeof(struct rel_list));
        newleaf->codice_rel=x; /*assign the node number*/
        //newleaf->rel=lista; //link the list
        newleaf->nome_rel=(char*)malloc(strlen(nome_relazione)+1);
        strcpy(newleaf->nome_rel, nome_relazione);
        newleaf->rel=add_rel_list(newleaf->rel, id_orig); /*helper function to add the list names*/
        newleaf->num_rel=1; /*metto a 1 la quantit‡ del tipo di relazioni esistenti*/
        struct tree *y= nil;
        struct tree *w= radice;
        while(w!=nil){
            y=w;
            if(newleaf->codice_rel<w->codice_rel){
                w=w->left;
            }
            else{
                w=w->right;
            }
            newleaf->prev=y;
            if (y==nil){
                radice=newleaf; //l'albero Ë vuoto
            }
            else if(newleaf->codice_rel<y->codice_rel){
                if(newleaf->codice_rel<y->left->codice_rel){
                    newleaf->right=y->left;
                }
                else{
                    newleaf->left=y->left;
                }
                y->left=newleaf;
            }
            else{
                if(newleaf->codice_rel<y->right->codice_rel){
                    newleaf->right=y->right;
                }
                else{
                    newleaf->left=y->right;
                }
                y->right=newleaf;
            }
            newleaf->black=0;
            insert_fixup(radice, newleaf, nil);
            return radice;
        }
    }
}

struct tree *insert_rel(unsigned long int x, char *id_orig, struct tree *radice, struct tree *nil, char *id_dest, char *nomerel, controllo * controllore){ 
//non relevant to the problem
    return radice;
}

void insert_fixup(struct tree *radice, struct tree* nuovo, struct tree *nil){
    //this function is used to balance the tree
}
```

the function should create a new node and link it inside the tree. the calls that are in the function and that I did not post are irrelevant to the problem, leftrotate and rightrotate are for the manipulation of the RB-Tree. when, later on, I look inside the tree for the attributes (relations) the only one saved is the first one, the root of the tree. using gdb the linking is correct but when I return to the main part of the code I lose all the new nodes of the tree

Comment: When you say "when i return the new nodes are lost", what do you mean by that? "Lost" how? And how do you use your `insert` function? Do you take care to save the pointer the function returns? And what happens if the `while` loop ends, what is returned then? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us (with emphasis on the *minimal* part), and please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And while it can be hard with trees and recursive functions, please try to step through the code with a debugger to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: by "when i return" i mean when the function ends and i return to main if i look in the tree with gdb in `root->left` or `root->right` i have the `nil` pointer as before the `addrel` function at all, like nothing has been added but the memory is still beeing allocated because using the program I get stack overflow so I assume returning the root node loses the pointers to the other nodes

Comment: is possible that the `insert` function deletes the new pointers being a `void` type?

Comment: Again, *how do you **call** the `insert` function?* Do you use the pointer it returns, or the pointer you pass in as the `radice` argument? And what happens if the `while` loop ends and you don't return anything?

Comment: I use the pointer passed as `radice` argument

Comment: Then that's probably the problem. Remember that in C arguments are passed *by value*, which means the value is copied into the local argument variable of the function. Modifying the copy (like doing `radice = malloc(...)`) in the function will not modify the original value you used when calling the function. Use the pointer it *returns* instead. And make sure that *all* paths of a function returns a valid value.